# Proxmox can't backup to CIFS mount hosted on a QNAP NAS

Tags: nas, samba, proxmox

I just added a CIFS mount to my little proxmox cluster. I was using it for backups when I only had one node and it worked.
But now that I have mounted it at a cluster level I am not able to backup to it. I get a permission error. However I am able to see the contents on the web interface, and if I ssh into any node I can write to the share if I use the root user. I see the mount is being added with user ID 0, that's probably why only root can write to it.
I'm using an specific user created on my NAS just for that for samba share.

Comment: So mount with the `uid=` (and maybe also `gid=`) option set to the id of the user that writes to the mount?

Comment: That may work. There is a backup user `# id backup
uid=34(backup) gid=34(backup) groups=34(backup)`. The only limitation is that, in order for proxmox to "see" the mount I have to use their mount tool. I'll see if there is the option to specify the UID